# Can't remove intermediate filesystems of Docker containers

Tags: docker

I'm having an issue when implementing my DevOps tools with Jenkinsfile and Dockerfile.

After running several times my pipeline based on Jenkinsfile and using docker, my server's storage keeps growing. When I run `df -h` in my linux server, I can see that there are a lot of filesystems of containers that shouldn't be there because, from what I see, those are from intermediate container created during the execution of the Jenkins pipeline.

I've already use `docker system prune` commands but I can't reclaim the space of those "dangling" filesystems. If I list all containers and all images, it doesn't show any dangling container or image that is using that space. I believe that it is related to my Dockerfile, which uses multistage build to create an intermediate image and then create the final image based on the previous one, but i'm not shure.

Here's an image of the filesystems that my installation has:

[Filesytems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3Ftx.png)

Here's an extract of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.16.1 AS BUILDER
.
.
.
RUN npm run build

FROM node:10.16.1 AS ARTIFACT
.
.
COPY --from=BUILDER /origin /destination
EXPOSE port
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Here's my docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:      18.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.37
 Go version:   go1.9.5
 Git commit:   9ee9f40
 Built:        Thu Apr 26 07:20:16 2018
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
 Orchestrator: swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      18.03.1-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.5
  Git commit:   9ee9f40
  Built:        Thu Apr 26 07:23:58 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

Linux distro of my server:

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.5 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.5"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.5:GA:server"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.5
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.5"
```

Does anybody know how to reclaim that space of those filesystems that I'm not using? And why is this happening?

Thank you!

Comment: What is you linux distro and version, this would help addressing the issue.

Comment: I updated my post with this info. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try with "docker system prune -a --volumes". Carefull with this one if you are not sure of the end result. Use with caution and in a pre-production environment if you have any doubt.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too but didn't reclaim any space.

Comment: FWIW - did you try 'docker system df -v'?

Comment: Yes, but it only appears the info of the 3 containers I'm actually running.